# Sending data from ROS to server-socket

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey ROS-community,

i got stuck with a problem:

I created a Ros topic, which publishes me an array of angles in a frequency of 1hz.

Now i want to send those angles to a robot control, which is a server-socket.

I now need some kind of client-socket to sent the data to the robot control.

What is the common way to do this in ROS?

Looking for a solution i always found something about the ros_bridge_suite.
But the tutorials only show how to create a ros bridge server.

I got the IP and the Port number of the server, how can i connect to it?

Thanks for help.

Best regards,
Carl

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214730/sending-data-from-ros-to-server-socket/) by [Carl](https://answers.ros.org/users/22443/carl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to do something similar, but in the reverse direction. The [implementation](https://github.com/allenh1/vanderbilt-ros-pkg/tree/master/tcp_command) is a little old (uses rosbuild), but can be updated pretty easily. If you need help with updating it to catkin, just let me know.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0